# Passing variable from one postman collection to another using command line tool Newman

Tags: unit-testing, q, postman, newman

I had two separate postman collection `preReq.json` and `postReq.json` which has different set of request.
from `preReq` collection I'm getting some value which I need to pass on second collection `postReq.json`
Both collection are using same environment file

Is there any way to pass environment variables to different collection suit

command:

```
newman run preReq.json -e Demo_Beta.json -k 

newman run postReq.json -e Demo_Beta.json -k
```

I want to set a value which i get from preReq.json to postReq.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Postman:**

You could save your dynamic value in your environment.

In `preReq.json` - Tests tab:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("value", value);
```

Now in your second collection `postReq.json` you can just reference this value with `{{value}}` in the URL editor.

If you want to reference your value in tests you can use:
`postman.getEnvironmentVariable('value')'` or `postman['value']`.

After you're done with your requests & tests you can clear the variable with:

```
postman.clearEnvironmentVariable("value");
```

**In newman:**

You could use the following combination:

```
newman run preReq.json -e Demo_Beta.json -k --export-environment Demo_Beta.json

newman run postReq.json -e Demo.Beta.json -k
```

The problem is the exported JSON file is not correct and misses the name property. I'll open an issue for that on the newman Github repository. For now you'll have to add name property manually.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Your suggestion will work for requests within same collection (chaining of request) in postman app, but I'm using newman command line tool for executing different collection suits which are exported from postman

Comment: I added an option for newman. Unfortunately the export environment option is buggy at the moment. So you'll have do some extra work but in general it works. See here for more info: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/573

Comment: got the problem --export-environment helps but since its buggy, have to put some manual efforts. Hope for the fix, thanks for link its like bulls eye

Comment: Postman labs fixed issue with export-environment in version 3.2.0